# Material Preview - OK / Render Preview - Black and White

Tags: materials, render-layers

I was working in a scene and, suddenly, all the Render preview and render itself got Black/white (no shades at all).
Material Preview continues ok, it happens only on render.  For both Evee and Cycles.

Curiously, I have tried to install an old add-on package and it crashed, but i checked and the add-on was not installed at all (probably because it was made for a very outdated blender version).

Here's my configs.

- Version 3.1.2
- System - Linux U. 20.4
- Only CPU.

[image: Evee Material Preview]

[image: Material _preview]

Curiously, the material tab also shows everything in B/W

[image]